# WPF Adorner and ICollectionView Refresh

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box bound to a collection of items.
Whenever i call a Refresh on a CollectionView of bound items the adorners disappear from list box items.

Can somebody explain why and how i can overcome this?
Should i re-add adorners after each refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adorner is linked to a particular element, in your case it seems like you are adorning `ListBoxItem` elements.

When you call the `Refresh` method on the collection view, this will cause the `ListBox` control to delete all of its existing `ListBoxItem` children and recreate them. Your adorners are "disappearing" because the elements they are adorning have been deleted by the list box.

You can either recreate the adorners or try to find some way of refreshing your list box that doesn't involve refreshing the collection view.